# How to mutate iterator elements in Rust to reverse substrings

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a function that will do the following:
**input:** a `String` of arbitrary length of the form "abc/def/ghi"
**output:** a `String` where all the substrings separated by "/" are reversed; in this example, the output would be "cba/fed/ihg".

More than the function itself, I care about the general principle behind mutating an iterator generated by the `split()` function.

Below is my best effort:

```
fn reverse_string(input: &mut str) -> String {
    input
        .to_string()
        .split('/')
        .map(move |x| x.to_string().rev())
        .collect::<String>()
}
```

The compiler complains that

```
error[E0599]: no method named `rev` found for type `std::string::String` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:37
  |
5 |         .map(move |x| x.to_string().rev())
  |                                     ^^^
  |
  = note: the method `rev` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `&mut std::string::String : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut str : std::iter::Iterator`
```

What does that mean and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Add `use std::iter::Iterator;` to the top of your file. The `Iterator` method needs to be in scope to use the `rev` method defined in it.

Comment: @EvilTak `Iterator` is in the prelude, so you never have to `use` it. The error message clearly says that the trait bounds are not satisfied. "The following trait is implemented but not in scope" is a different message.

Comment: @trentcl Ah, misread the error. Read "the following trait..." and instantly assumed an out-of-scope error :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are learning iterators, I suggest first deciding *what* you want to do, before actually doing it.

For example, here is an example with a single memory allocation:

```
fn reverse_string(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(input.len());

    for portion in input.split('/') {
        if !result.is_empty() {
            result.push('/');
        }
        for c in portion.chars().rev() {
            result.push(c);
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Iterators generally are focused on *pure* methods which do not modify their environment. Unfortunately, this can lead to inefficiencies here as this would imply creating and dropping `String` left and right.

Now, technically you *can* mutate the environment in `map` (it takes a `FnMut`), it's just frowned upon because by convention readers expect it to be pure.

As a result, when you want to bring additional state in, `Iterator::fold` is the go-to method:

```
fn reverse_string(input: &str) -> String {
    input
        .split('/')
        .fold(
            String::with_capacity(input.len()),
            |mut acc, portion| {
                if !acc.is_empty() {
                    acc.push('/');
                }
                for c in portion.chars().rev() {
                    acc.push(c);
                }
                acc
            }
        )
}
```

The first argument is an accumulator, which is passed to each invocation of the closure, which then return it. Finally, at the end of the `fold` call, the accumulator is then returned.

This is equivalent to the first function, both in terms of logic and efficiency, but honestly here I kinda prefer the `for` version to be honest.

Comment: Notes: (1) I have not found a way to append an `Iterator<Item = char>` to a `String` and (2) I wonder if there's a way to generate an `Iterator` of `Iterator` and then flatten the hell out of it with a `flat_join` call or something.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt:

```
fn reverse_string(input: &mut str) -> String {
    input.split('/') // split the input string by '/'
         .map(|x| x.chars().rev().collect::<String>()) // reverse the sections and collect them
         .collect::<Vec<String>>() // collect the reversed sections into a vector of Strings
         .join("/") // join the strings so they are connected by '/' again
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("abc/def/ghi");

    println!("{}", reverse_string(&mut s)); // cba/fed/ihg
}
```

The main error in your code was that you tried to iterate a `String`, but it doesn't implement `Iterator`; it needs to be iterated over either its [`.chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) or [`.bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.bytes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer!
Just to understand the error message better, `std::string::String : std::iter::Iterator` is telling me the String doesn't implement the trait, I get that now. What does the second line, `str : std::iter::Iterator` mean? Is that just a reference to the file where the rev method is defined?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the creation of a `Vec` during `collect::<Vec<String>>`? (i.e. joining without temporary vectors)

Comment: @SquattingSlavInTracksuit since `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`, it inherits all the methods of `str`. The error indicates that neither `String` nor the methods it inherits from `str` allow it to be treated like an `Iterator`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo perhaps someone with a stronger Iterator-foo will find a way :).

Comment: @ljedrz: It's doable with `fold` (see https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=262563bc48d4afb5dddda9182aecec3f&version=stable) but still doesn't avoid the intermediate `String` in `map`, and is kinda uglyish.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo The `itertools` crate [has a `join` method](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.4/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join) that lets you [just drop the second `collect`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=316d478469879565933a669f654a9c67&version=stable). (Also note that `reverse_string` doesn't need `&mut` anymore)

Answer (score 3):

Reversing by `.chars()` may be acceptable sometimes... but why did Ukraine become Australia?

```
println!("{}", reverse_string("abc/df/ghi")); // prints cba/fd/ihg
```

(Each flag emoji is made of two code points that spell a country code, and Australia's (AU) is the reverse of Ukraine's (UA). Strange things can also happen with non-emoji characters, like ñ.)

Fortunately, this is easy to fix with the `unicode-segmentation` crate; let's just take [Matthieu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793521/3650362), replacing `chars()` with `graphemes(true)` and `push` with `push_str`:

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

fn reverse_string(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(input.len());

    for portion in input.split('/') {
        if !result.is_empty() {
            result.push('/');
        }
        for g in portion.graphemes(true).rev() {
            result.push_str(g);
        }
    }

    result
}
```

Now all our flags look right again ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f5a71ad1f5c0c461babb367fde285b36&version=stable)).